# neo4j find the alternate path of all existing paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to model a graph to all the routes including the routes with different origin. So for example I have the following graph

```
Route1(Train1) : ST_B--------->ST2----->ST3--->ST4 --> ST5--->ST_E
Route2(Train2) : ST_C-------->ST4---->ST5------>ST_E
```

I am trying to get the list of routes from ST_B-------->ST_E and it should return as follows but not able to get a solution for the second journey:

```
Journey1 : (Train1) : ST_B--------->ST2----->ST3---ST4 --ST5--->ST_E
Journey2 : (Train1) : ST_B--------->ST2----->ST3---ST4.
           (Train2) : ST4---->ST5------>ST_E
```

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question, but unfortunately, it is not very clear. In particular, you use the term "Route" ambiguously. I imagine that there are two Routes (`Route1` and `Route2`), served by two Trains (`Train1` and `Train2`). Using these Routes, you would like to design *trips* from station ST_B to ST_E, where a trip may use multiple routes (e.g. trip 2 uses `Route1` from ST_B to ST4, where it changes to `Route2` to continue to ST_E). Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: yes. I need to find all possible routes.  Route1 : ST_B to ST_E, and for Route2 : Switch to train2 from  ST4 and reach ST_E.

Comment: I am planning to find the nodes with more than one incoming edge as the break point of the journey. Need to find whether it is achievable using Cypher query

Comment: Please provide the queries you've tried so far. If possible, please provide the cypher to create an example graph so we can better attempt to find a query that will work, since we won't be able to tell if the model needs adjustment for an efficient query to work.